# Maping `:vs|term` to a single key is not working as expected in Vim

Tags: vim, keymapping, neovim

I want to open terminal in a vertical split with `<C-t>` or possibly a single key.
I tried `:map <C-t> :vs|term`, but after this every time I open Vim, the terminal opens on its own (and still in horizontal view).

I just wanna open terminal in a vertical split with one mapping.

Comment: **Vim** or **Neovim**? In the former, `:term` opens its own window while in the latter, `:term` opens a terminal instance in the current window. The solution to your problem depends on which editor you use so you should make sure your question is correctly worded and tagged.

Answer (score 1):

Character `|` has special meaning in VimL - it allows you to write multiple commands in one line (e.g. in command-line mode). Fox example: `:echo "aaa" | let g:foo = 12 | echo g:foo`

So `:map <C-t> :vs|term` is essentially equivalent of:

```
:map <C-t> :vs
term
```

So for Vim it means that you want to map <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> to `:vs` and then open terminal.

If you want to open terminal vertically, then you should use `:vertical` command before `:terminal` command, like so:

```
:vertical :terminal
```

To map it to <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> you should do: `nnoremap <C-t> :vert term<CR>`

If you want to create a mapping with `|` character, you need to substitute it with `<bar>`,
i.e.: `:vs | term` in mapping would be `:map <C-t> :vs <bar> term`

Comment: I experience the same problem.  map <F2> :split | terminal ++curwin   causes Gvim to open with only one pane open and with the terminal active in that pane.  It did NOT wait for me to press <F2> before applying the action.